# "Helloworld" c program failed on my new ubuntu 20.04

Tags: openjdk, c

[when i build hello world program on eclips they are showing this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYJCC.png)

when i build helloworld program on c on eclips this is shown on console:-

10:21:36 **** Build of configuration Debug for project sample ****
make all
Cannot run program "make": Unknown reason

Error: Program "make" not found in PATH
PATH=[/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin]

10:21:36 Build Failed. 1 errors, 0 warnings. (took 26ms)

---

i downloaded open jdk 11
when check java version it shown as

```
openjdk version "11.0.11" 2021-04-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.20.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.20.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

i have searched this problem on internet , but i didn't found any solution  =======

Answer (score 3):

C does not need openjdk. You need `build-essential` and `make` in this case.
Simply type in the terminal `sudo apt install build-essential make`

I don't use eclipse so I don't know if you need to configure the makefile too.

Comment: thank you for your help , it is working

Answer (score 1):

Before proceeding you have to install needed build tools by

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

For C/C++ development in Eclipse you have to install correct addon. Visit *Help* → *Eclipse Marketplace* and install Eclipse C/C++ CDT.

[image: Eclipse CDT]

Then restart Eclipse to create project from *File* → *New* → *Project*, *C/C++*, *C Project*, *Hello World ANSI C Project*.
Finally build it by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, run with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>.

Comment: it is working , from Eclips Marketplace i can able to update eclips too . and now the problem is solved , it was a great help

Comment: Great! So you can accept this my answer by using grey checkmark at the left of this answer.