# No network driver, ubuntu 20.04.4 server

Tags: networking, drivers, wired

I tried to install network driver on my newest motherboard, but unable to. Please help.
Motherboard: ASUS PRIME Z690-P WIFI D4
Ubuntu: 20.04.4 server

[Picture of fault](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlLgN.jpg)

Comment: 'make' is included in the package 'build-essential' that you must install, along with its many dependencies, before you can compile a driver from source code. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: where can i download this essential package on this computer (windows), so i can put it on a usb stick, and then install it from the usb stick into the ubuntu server (that lack internet) so that i can get internet on it? I need atleast "make".. but i would assume i need alot more programs/apps than "make" for it all to work.. ; basicly the essentials.. wich leads me back to the question: Where can i download the essentials to my usbstick, and how do i install them from that usbstick into my ubuntu?

Comment: You can download any package from https://packages.ubuntu.com  Although you might only need to download https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=build-essential&searchon=names&suite=jammy&section=all

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Helloworld" c program failed on my new ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1379281/helloworld-c-program-failed-on-my-new-ubuntu-20-04)

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal commands: `sudo dmesg | grep r81` and also: `ls /usr/lib/firmware/rtl_nic/ | grep 8125` and, finally: `uname -r` Possible reference: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware/+bug/1916558

Comment: Ty for lot of good comments to fix this. And sorry to say i dont know if any of it helps or how. My solution: I ended up with installing proxmox instead, and run several ubuntus from there.. wich is a better soluten anyway, all in all. And network worked right away in that version. Again, ty :)